# Does the following statement hold? If |sin(z)|<1 then Im(z)=0.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to prove or disprove the following statement:

If  $  |\sin(z)|<1$  then   $Im(z)=0 $  for all complex numbers $z$.

In my opinion this statement its not true if we take the following counterexample:

If we take $z=0.5i$ then

$$\begin{align}|\sin(z)|&=\left|\frac{e^{i(0.5i)}-e^{-i(0.5i)}}{2i}\right|\\
&=\frac{\left|e^{i(0.5i)}-e^{-i(0.5i)}\right|}{2|i|}\\
&=\frac{\left|e^{(-0.5)}-e^{(0.5)}\right|}{2}\\
&=\frac{\left|1-e^{2\cdot(0.5)}\right|}{2e^{(0.5)}}<\frac{|1-e|}{2}<1\end{align}$$

But $Im(z)=0.5$ which is clearly not $0$

Im not sure if i chose the right example to prove this.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your solution is correct.

Comment: You can also look through Liouville's theorem eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is false, but $|\sin (z)|\le 1$ does place a bound on $|y|$.

Take real and imaginary parts, and add their squares, thus:

$|\sin (z)|^2=\sin^2 (x)\cosh^2 (y)+\cos^2 (x)\sinh^2 (y)$

$=\sin^2 (x)+(\sin^2 (x)+\cos^2 (x)) (\sinh^2 (y)) $

$=\sin^2 (x)+\sinh^2 (y)$

So $|\sin (z)|\le 1$ implies $|y| \le \sinh^{-1} (1) $.

Comment: Clear! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: And $\sinh^{-1}(1)=\log(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your answer is fine.

It's worth noting that if you've got any $w$, you can find a complex $x$ such that $2iw=x-\frac{1}{x}$ by solving the quadratic equation: $x^2-(2iw)x-1=0$. Since $x$ is not zero, we can find $z$ such that $x=e^{iz}$. Then you have: $w=\sin z$. So $\sin$ is onto the complex plane.

Since $\sin(z)$ is real if $\mathrm{Im}(z)=0$, there are a lot of other values $|w|<1$ that are not real that need to be accounted for.